# android send image to servlet using the imageview and HttpPost

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which I use ImageView to capture an image using camera.

So how can I send the captured image in imageview to a java servlet as multipart using httppost.

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            view.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();             

            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean `How can i send byte array b to the server?`.

Comment: Yes.How can I send bytearray b to server using httppost or any other method and then save image on sever using the servlet?

Comment: You did not tell how the servlet expects that data is send. So then we cannot help you. If you want things to send with HttpPost well thats ok. Very easy to send a byte array. Code you can find if you read ten pages (50 threads) from this website with tag android.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Example code:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    writeStream(out);

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Please refer to section Posting Content.